# Munkres, Analysis on Manifolds section 11 q8

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am reading Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres and I am struggling in a question in section 11 about integration. The question is

Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f : Q \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Show that if $f$ vanishes except on a closed set $B$ of measure zero, then $\int_Q f$ exists and equals zero.

Let $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in Q \setminus B$ and $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in B$. Can I conclude that $f$ is continuous on $Q \setminus B$ as it is a constant function here? If this is true, then by theorem 11.2, $f$ is integrable over $A$.

Theorem 11.2: Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f : Q \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Let $D$ be the set of points of $Q$ at which $f$ fails to be continuous. Then $\int_Q f$ exists if and only if $D$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I also did it the way you propose but I do not know if that can be done, I hope someone answers if it can be done or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is bounded and $$\int_Qf=\int_B  f$$Now $$|\int_B f  dm| \le \int_B|f|dm \le Mm(B)=0$$

Comment: I also did it in the way proposed by the one who asked the question, can it be done that way?